# Excel getting nearest value and finding corresponding column

Tags: arrays, excel

I have the following table:

```
         A             B
```

**1**  |    262  |  22.6 |  *454*  **||**   255  |  23.2  | *442* |
**2**  |    327  |  18.1 |  *566*  **||**   320  |  18.5  | *554* |
**3**  |    452  |  13.1 |  *782*  **||**   442  |  13.4  | *765* |

Where the A corresponds with the 3 columns below.

- I want to get the nearest value of the **3th** column of A or B depending on another cell value. **The first and second** column in A remain unused
- Then get the column (A, B) and the row (1, 2, 3) to use for another function

So lets say I have a value of *570*. The nearest value in the 3th column would be **566**. My column would be **A** and row **2**

```
=INDEX(Blad2!D2:D26;MATCH(MIN(ABS(Blad2!D2:D26-D30));ABS(Blad2!D2:D26-D30);0))
```

This is the formula I currently use for determining the nearest value. It works perfectly but if I try to get it's values from multiple arrays, the automatic "**;**" sign will make excel see the next array as a new argument for the Index function.

- Can both problems be solved within excel functions or do I need a macro?

Comment: Why are you using `;`? Also, what do you mean by "the next array"? Are you dragging a formula downward and the reference to the array/range does not stay fixed?

Comment: He's using semicolons because he's overseas and the argument delimiter overseas is a semicolon and not a comma.  You can tell because instead of Sheet2 it is Blad2 and "Blad" is the Dutch word for Sheet

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do but:

{="A"&MATCH(INDEX(D2:D26;MATCH(MIN(ABS(D2:D26-D30));ABS(D2:D26-D30);0));D:D;0)-1}

might suit.